# how to solve the allignment problems in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, css, html

I designing one web site.The Site is clearly opened in google chrome and firefox but its not clearly opened in internet explorer also the pages are merging with each other.Please tell me the procedure to solve it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  after that post your question.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't provide the code to your web page, then try this fix: give your container element a `zoom:1;` that should solve your problem

Comment: Sir The Site link is http://www.uniqueinsurance.co.in/ .Please open by using chrome and IE and see the differents.

Comment: all looks good except for the main photo on the home page, do you have the latest version of IE

Comment: thank you sir now its works in latest version of IE.

Comment: Is It Possible to view the site in IE8.

Comment: I see your problem, did you get the main photo problem fixed, and do you need help with the IE8 problems?